# Web Application with Maven not create connection pool and JNDI automaticly in Glassfish

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, netbeans, glassfish

When I deploy my web application witch use **JDBC Connection pool** and **JNDI** with **Netbeans**, this both created automaticly in **Glassfish**.

When I use **Maven** to create the same application, the JDBC Connection pool and JNDI **not create automaticly** and show me this error:

**Error**

```
Grave: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : moduleJNDI__pm
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : moduleJNDI__pm
```

I know the solution of this error, I just create the **JNDI manualy**.

My Question is: is there any solution or configuration to create the JNDI automaticly in the server Glassfish like the ordinary application, or is that a problem with Maven.

**N.B**

I use the server: **Glassfish 3.1.2.2**, **Netbeans 8.1**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `glassfish-resources.xml` file to define your database connection and make sure it ends up in your `WEB-INF` folder. You could just put it there as a static file, but in most projects I work on I need a different connection in development.  You could use the Maven [WAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) to take care of that (handling it as a filterable resource). For example, create the `glassfish-resources.xml` in your project at `/src/main/resources_WEB-INF`. Now you can put it in your `WEB-INF` folder when you build your project. See this `pom.xml` fragment:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources_WEB-INF</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

See also

- [how to deploy a webapp and create its resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530730/how-to-deploy-a-webapp-and-create-its-resources)
- [Creating a Simple Web Application Using a MySQL Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html)

Comment: Thank you @Jasper de Vries for your answer, i will test it soon