# JBoss Wildfly - Authentication of Web App against LDAP

Tags: authentication, ldap, jboss7.x, jsf-2.2, wildfly

I have a security domain defined in jboss-web.xml as below

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/my_ldap_security_domain</security-domain>
    <disable-audit>true</disable-audit>
</jboss-web>
```

I also have defined inside my standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
    <security-domains>
        <security-domain name="my_ldap_security_domain" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="sufficient">
                    <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                    <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy"/>
                    <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
                    <module-option name="bindDN" value="temp@my.domain"/>
                    <module-option name="bindCredential" value="mypass"/>
                    <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="DC=my,DC=domain"/>
                    <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
                    <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="DC=my,DC=domain"/>
                    <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(uniquemember={1})"/>
                    <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                    <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                    <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="0"/>
                    <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="true"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
    </security-domains>
</subsystem>
```

My only realms present on my standalone.xml are

```
<security-realms>
    <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
        <authentication>
            <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
            <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </authentication>
        <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
            <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </authorization>
    </security-realm>
    <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
        <authentication>
            <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
            <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </authorization>
    </security-realm>
</security-realms>
```

I did not mention it before because i presumed that this security realms were meant to authenticate the application server console access.  Sorry for that.

My doubt is how to create a jsf2 login page to authenticate against what is defined above.  I read a lot of articles about but still in the same place beacause most articles use a fake authentication as example (comparing with static strings instead of showing how to consult LDAP server).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you tekk me how do you get application-roles.properties users on java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i presumed that this security realms were meant to authenticate the application server console access

You're partially correct there. The `name="ManagementRealm"` does indeed specify a realm config for accessing admin functions. `name="ApplicationRealm"` would be the attribute to specify for securing a web application

Your current realm config is missing some things necessary for LDAP authentication. I presume you're already familiar with the login-form configuration in *web.xml*. Your realm configuration should look something like the following, an excerpt from the [Wildfly 8 Realm Configuration Manual](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Security+Realms):

```
<management>
  <security-realms>
    <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
      <authentication>
        <ldap connection="EC2" base-dn="CN=Users,DC=darranl,DC=jboss,DC=org">
          <username-filter attribute="sAMAccountName" />
        </ldap>
      </authentication>
    </security-realm>
 
  </security-realms>
</management>
```

Where the `<ldap>` tag specifies that your lookup is against an LDAP server. Beyond this, you only need follow the standard auth methods for a JavaEE application.

The takeaway from this should be that web application security within JavaEE generally takes the same approach of

1. Setting up a realm (App-server specific)
2. Setting up security constraints in web.xml (uniform across all JavaEE applications)
3. Implementing a login method (Configuration or Programmatic)

**Related**

- [Java EE 6 Programmatic security, glassfish and JDBC realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084710/java-ee-6-programmatic-security-glassfish-and-jdbc-realm)
- [How to properly logout of a Java EE 6 Web Application after logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893727/how-to-properly-logout-of-a-java-ee-6-web-application-after-logging-in)
- [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/performing-user-authentication-in-java-ee-jsf-using-j-security-check)

Comment: Sorry for only being able to answer almost a month after your post.  I really like what you said but I am still insecure with the 3 steps approach you just mention before.

The realm I think it is fine, although I still have lots of doubts about ApplicationRealm, authentication, authorization and outbound-connections that you did not mention in your answer. I have no idea what would it be using my scenario as an example.

The security constraints I am reading here - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html about form based.

But what about  login method by Configuration?

Comment: I didn't talk about any of that in my answer, because your question was not about any of that. You haven't actually asked a question about any of that even now. What do you mean by "doubts"? If you ask a specific question, I'll be able to give a specific answer. My answer was posted with the presumption that you have a basic understanding of authentication and authorization in a javaee webapp. You should get that sorted first @DanielFerreiraCastro

Comment: See, I am not complaining at all.  What you just wrote helped me a lot.  But regarding the doubts I wrote before what would be the best way you could help?  Do you think that another post making my points clearer would be the way? Could you answer there?

Comment: You're better off asking a whole, separate question @DanielFerreiraCastro

Comment: @DanielFerreiraCastro did you manage to resolve? I have the same doubt and I'm running in a authentication trouble. Could you please post what was the specific parts of your standalone.xml or domain.xml realm/ldap configuration?

Comment: Not yet.  But I had to stop my studies for this particular case.